# Al hacer scroll en RecyclerView me muestra un TextView que no corresponde con el nombre de cada imagen

Tags: android, recyclerview

Tengo un recyclerview que se pobla desde un array que contiene imagenes de autos y las marcas de los mismos mediante la librería Glide. Debajo de cada imagen ubiqué un textview que es donde aparece la marca de cada auto, resulta que al ejecutar la aplicación me ubica bien las marcas correspondientes a cada imagen, pero al hacer scroll y cambiar la vista del recyclerview las marcas ya no corresponden a cada auto y al regresar con scroll hacia arriba también se pierde la concordancia de cada imagen con su respectivo textview. Supongo que es en la asignación del textview con el respectivo item del arreglo, pero le he buscado de todas formas y no logro encontrar el problema. Será posible que alguno de ustedes me echen una mano, les estaré muy agradecido. Les dejo los layouts y código relacionados. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Activity Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_images);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    ImageGalleryAdapter adapter = new ImageGalleryAdapter(this, SpacePhoto.getSpacePhotos());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private class ImageGalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageGalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder>  {

    private TextView nombreCoche;

    @Override
    public ImageGalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View photoView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_photo, parent, false);
        ImageGalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder viewHolder = new ImageGalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder(photoView);

        nombreCoche = (TextView) photoView.findViewById(R.id.nombre_coche);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ImageGalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        SpacePhoto spacePhoto = mSpacePhotos[position];
        ImageView imageView = holder.mPhotoImageView;

        final SpacePhoto item = getItem(position);
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(spacePhoto.getIdDrawable())
                //.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_cloud_off_red)
                .into(imageView);
        nombreCoche.setText(item.getNombre());
    }

    public SpacePhoto getItem(int position) {
        return (SpacePhoto.getSpacePhotos()[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (mSpacePhotos.length);
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public ImageView mPhotoImageView;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            mPhotoImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                SpacePhoto spacePhoto = mSpacePhotos[position];
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SpacePhotoActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(SpacePhotoActivity.EXTRA_SPACE_PHOTO, spacePhoto);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }

    private SpacePhoto[] mSpacePhotos;
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageGalleryAdapter(Context context, SpacePhoto[] spacePhotos) {
        mContext = context;
        mSpacePhotos = spacePhotos;
    }
}
}
```

Fuente de datos:

```
public class SpacePhoto implements Parcelable {
private String nombre;
private int idDrawable;

public SpacePhoto(String nombre, int idDrawable) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.idDrawable = idDrawable;
}

protected SpacePhoto(Parcel in) {
    nombre = in.readString();
    idDrawable = in.readInt();
}

public static final Creator<SpacePhoto> CREATOR = new Creator<SpacePhoto>() {
    @Override
    public SpacePhoto createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new SpacePhoto(in);
    }

    @Override
    public SpacePhoto[] newArray(int size) {
        return new SpacePhoto[size];
    }
};

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public int getIdDrawable() {
    return idDrawable;
}

public int getId() {
    return nombre.hashCode();
}

public static  SpacePhoto[] getSpacePhotos() {

    return new SpacePhoto[]{
            new SpacePhoto("Jaguar F-Type 2015", R.drawable.jaguar_f_type_2015),
            new SpacePhoto("Mercedes AMG-GT", R.drawable.mercedes_benz_amg_gt),
            new SpacePhoto("Mazda MX-5", R.drawable.mazda_mx5_2015),
            new SpacePhoto("Porsche 911 GTS", R.drawable.porsche_911_gts),
            new SpacePhoto("BMW Serie 6", R.drawable.bmw_serie6_cabrio_2015),
            new SpacePhoto("Ford Mondeo", R.drawable.ford_mondeo),
            new SpacePhoto("Volvo V60 Cross Country", R.drawable.volvo_v60_crosscountry),
            new SpacePhoto("Jaguar XE", R.drawable.jaguar_xe),
            new SpacePhoto("VW Golf R Variant", R.drawable.volkswagen_golf_r_variant_2015),
            new SpacePhoto("Seat León ST Cupra", R.drawable.seat_leon_st_cupra),
            new SpacePhoto("Aston Martin One-77", R.drawable.aston_martin_one_77),
            new SpacePhoto("Bugatti Chiron", R.drawable.bugatti_chiron),
            new SpacePhoto("Ferrari F60 América", R.drawable.ferrari_f60_america),
            new SpacePhoto("Koenigsegg CCXR Trevita", R.drawable.koenigsegg_ccxr_trevita),
            new SpacePhoto("Koenigsegg One", R.drawable.koenigsegg_one),
            new SpacePhoto("Koenigsegg Regera", R.drawable.koenigsegg_regera),
            new SpacePhoto("Lamborghini Veneno", R.drawable.lamborghini_veneno),
            new SpacePhoto("Lykan Hypersport", R.drawable.lykan_hypersport),
            new SpacePhoto("Maybach Exelero", R.drawable.maybach_exelero),
            new SpacePhoto("Pagani Huayra_BC", R.drawable.pagani_huayra_bc),
    };
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(nombre);
    parcel.writeInt(idDrawable);
}

public static SpacePhoto getItem(int id) {
    for (SpacePhoto item : getSpacePhotos()) {
        if (item.getId() == id) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Layout Activity Main:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_images"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Layout del detalle del RecyclerView:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_photo"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nombre_coche"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es en el Adapter, aunque obtienes el item,

```
  final SpacePhoto item = getItem(position);
```

en realidad estas cargando la misma imagen:

```
            .load(spacePhoto.getIdDrawable())
```

Debes obtener la imagen del item que en ese momento se esta procesando,

```
 .load(item.getIdDrawable()) //*Carga la imagen.
```

entonces sería:

```
   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ImageGalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        SpacePhoto spacePhoto = mSpacePhotos[position];
       // ImageView imageView = holder.mPhotoImageView;

        final SpacePhoto item = getItem(position);
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(item.getIdDrawable()) //*Carga la imagen.
                //.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_cloud_off_red)
                .into(holder.mPhotoImageView);
        //nombreCoche.setText(item.getNombre());
          holder.mTextView.setText(item.getNombre());
    }
```

Comment: Amigo, fijate que las imágenes me las carga bien en el orden en que están en el array, aunque yo haga ese cambio que sugieres que de hecho ya lo hice, el problema persiste con los textview que muestran información de cada imagen, sucede sólo cuando hago scroll en el recyclerview.

Comment: veo el problema que comentas de hecho en la clase estatica MyViewHolder debes agregar también el TextView ya que solo tienes el imageView:
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            mPhotoImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

Comment: realicé un cambio en el código de la respuesta para que veas lo que comento,para mayor entendimiento ve el método MyViewHolder  de la clase MyViewHolder  en este ejemplo:  https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-RecyclerView-HorizontalVertical/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/jorgesys/recyclerview/MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java

Comment: Ok estimado, revisaré el ejemplo y aplicaré los cambios que sugieres, muchas gracias de por toda la ayuda.

Comment: Sos un genio amigo, de tanto buscarle ya me estaba dando por vencido. Un millón de gracias por tomarte tiempo para ayudar.

Comment: Hola @MelvinPérez un placer ayudarte, solo es un poco de practica! recuerda que en el caso de RecyclerView es importante definir los "contenedores" en la clase "holder" ;). ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ